# SVNSERVE1.6.6 Upgrade or Migration advise?

Tags: svn, migration, upgrade, collabnet, svnserve

I'm looking for an upgrade solution from current our svnserve (1.6.6 version) setup to something else that offers LDAP authentication as well as granular level security (folder level restriction as opposed to all or nothing access).

As it stands, existing svnserve offers next to nothing in terms of security (username as password are the same; any user with SVN access can navigate to any project / folder which he should not have access to. I have looked at Collabnet Edge which perfectly fits our requirement but unfortunately it doesn't offer svnserve support.

I need to, obviously, preserve current repository and all its checkin / checkout history. Any advise would be of great help. if any of you have done this kind of migration and is willing to share the document, it would be awesome. Thanks. Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an SVN "dump" (there's plenty of info about that if you Google), and then import the dumped repositories into SVN Edge.

Answer (score 0):

As @crusader suggested, [you can move your repositories to another server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate). [SVNEdge does not support svnserve svn:// access](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#section-FrequentlyAskedQuestions-DoesItWorkWithOtherServersBesidesApache) so you will have to move to using HTTP(S).

Your users will be required to checkout their working copies again using new HTTP(S) URL or [`svn switch --relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html#adsense_bottom) their existing working copies to this new URL. Don't forget to point other services that access your repositories to new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install SVN Edge on the same server and point it at the folder that contains your repositories.  There is no need to do any migration or dump and load.  See:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/MigrationPath

SVN Edge does not support svnserve so you would need to transition to using https protocol but given that you are mentioning things like security, that is a good thing.  You can leave your existing svnserve process in tact while you transition.  It is OK to access the repository from more than one server process at the same time.

Once your users are all using the https server you can just stop the svnserve process and retire it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Apologies for the delayed response - I didn't get any email notification (bummer!)

Comment: Hi Mark, I have been able to perform this task by migrating to Edge but it doesn't support svn:// and caused performance overhead due to webDAV shortcomings. 

I went with SVN 1.8.5 instead and the upgrade worked like a charm. But I'm stuck trying to integrate it with AD using SASLAUTHD. I realize it doesn't compile on Windows but what about Kerberos authentication? can I use any other SASL apart from Cyrus but I believe that would mean Subversion has to be rebuilt with, say, GNU SASL functions? Is there anything I can do to use svnserve with LDAP? Thanks.

Comment: Don't waste your time. You will never get svnserve to work with Active Directory.

Comment: Cheers Mark! I've managed to get svnserve working with LDAP now.

Comment: You should post a detailed blog somewhere to help out the next guy then.  I've never seen it working anywhere.

Comment: Sure - will do. We used Cygwin to setup SVN over and configured SASLAUTHD plugin to enable AD authentication. Thanks.